# Spring request to return json OR xml response

Tags: json, xml, spring, http

I have a Spring request mapping that I would like to return XML by default, or JSON if specified in the request header. Here is some code:

**Request Mapping**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/batch/{progName}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/xml)
    public ResponseEntity<JobResults> processTestObject(@PathVariable("progName") String progName,
                                                        @RequestHeader("Content-Type") String contentType) throws Exception {
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = MccControllerUtils.createCacheDisabledHeaders();
        if(contentType.equals("application/json")) {
            responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        }
        LOGGER.info("Running batch program " + progName);
        JobResults response = batchService.processProgName(progName);
        return new ResponseEntity<JobResults>(response, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

- Using Postman with no Headers, when I hit this endpoint I receive a
  `400 Bad Request` status code.
- In Postman Headers field, if I specify `Content-Type` as
  `application/xml` I get correct XML response.
- If I specify `Content-Type` as `application/json` I get an error
  back: `Unexpected '<'`

**What I want:**

To return XML by default from the endpoint, and to return JSON if specified in the request

**EDIT**

As of now the request returns `400 Bad Request` when there is no `Accept` or `Content-Type` sent within Postman. In order to retrieve the desired response, I must specify the `Accept` and `Content-Type` to `application/xml`

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/batch/{progName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<JobResults> processTestObject(@PathVariable("progName") String progName,
                                                        @RequestHeader("Content-Type") MediaType contentType) throws Exception {
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = MccControllerUtils.createCacheDisabledHeaders();
        responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
        if(!contentType.toString().equals("*/*")) {
            responseHeaders.setContentType(contentType);
        }
        LOGGER.info("Running batch program " + progName);
        JobResults response = batchService.processProgName(progName);
        return new ResponseEntity<JobResults>(response, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example still takes `Content-Type` from the request where this should be `Accept`. Second, make sure that your JobResults object is serialisable by both the json marshaller and the xml marshaller. Third, if you want specific behaviour is json is requested, you should make the check on that specific media type and not a generic one like `"*/*"`.

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/batch/{progName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<JobResults> processTestObject(@PathVariable("progName") String progName,
                                                    @RequestHeader("Accept") MediaType accept) throws Exception {
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
    if(!accept.toString().equals("*/*")) {
        responseHeaders.setContentType(accept);
    }
    JobResults response = new JobResults("23423", "result");
    return new ResponseEntity<JobResults>(response, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Some response object, but annotated.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class JobResults {
    String id;
    String name;

    public JobResults(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    ....
}
```

Above code gives me `application/json` when requested through `Accept` header.

Comment: Postman allows you to add custom headers. `Content-Type` is used to describe the content of a request. `Accept-Type` is to convey your wishes for the response.

Comment: I'm not sure. When I submit a request to the endpoint with key `Accept-Type` and value `application/xml` it immediately returns a `400 Bad Request` When I google for "Accept-Type" I can't find any results of its usage

Comment: My bad. It's the `Accept` header. This page might help to make things clear: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-content-negotiation-json-xml

Comment: I've set the RequestMapping to produce both XML and JSON, and I now call the endpoint with a .xml or .json extension. Thanks, this solved half of my issues :P

Comment: You're welcome. What's the other half of your issues?

p.s. consider accepting the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Well, the problem is by default I want the request to return XML, and only JSON if specified

Comment: If you don't use extention but the header, like your original proposal, that should work.

Comment: It does not, the default request returns a 400 error per my original posting. I'm toying with it now

Comment: When debugging I found that if the header wasn't specified, the value was "*/*", what I understood to be a wildcard. I was implementing the ability to set the accept to any mediatype specified in the header. Thanks for your help